GitLab-Runner config runner, using private image
I deployed gitlab-runner in our k8s cluster.
this is the config of my runners:
  runners: ### overide by .argocd-source-gitlab-runner.yaml ###
    # runner configuration, where the multi line strings is evaluated as
    # template so you can specify helm values inside of it.
    #
    # tpl: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function
    # runner configuration: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html
    config: |
      [[runners]]
        [runners.kubernetes]
          namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
          image = "alpine"
          pull_policy = "always"
          helper_image = "xxx/xxx/gitlab-runner:alpine3.19-x86_64-v16.10.0"
          [runners.kubernetes.security_context]
            allow_privilege_escalation = false
            read_only_root_filesystem = true
            run_as_non_root = true
            privileged = false
            capabilities = ["ALL"]
            seccomp_profile_name = "runtime/default"

this private repo need authentication, how can i pass my config, the secret for pulling image from this repo is already in the namespace of gitlab-runner
Its not possible to pass the credentials in plain text in our values.yaml, because we don't want this.
